# HMAC SHA1 android with input string and input key is Hex String

Tags: android

this is my first post! So if anything is wrong please tell me, i am new to android developing! Here is my question:
 I am trying to generate HMAC-SHA1 with input is Hexstring for example the input key is "2cb1b780138bc273459232edda0e4b96" and input value is HexString too but way longer than the key, all the value and the key are Hexstring not character or normal string, so how can i achieve this? I searched a lot but all the result came to use the value and the key in normal string like "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

I tried using convertHextoString code to change my HexString into Character string and put in the function like you did but the converted String from convertHextoString appear to have many SPECIAL CHARACTERS such as "\n" or ":" or "%" and so on and i think that is the problem why i got the wrong output. Here is my convertHextoString function

```
public String convertHexToString(String hex){

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

  //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
  for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

      //grab the hex in pairs
      String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
      //convert hex to decimal
      int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
      //convert the decimal to character
      sb.append((char)decimal);

      temp.append(decimal);
  }
  System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

  return sb.toString();
}
```

and the function to HMAC:

```
static String hash_hmac(String type, String value, String key) {
try { Log.i("Hien - value - hmac",value);
javax.crypto.Mac mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(type);
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec secret = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), type);
mac.init(secret);
byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(digest.length*2);
String s;
for (byte b : digest){
s = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff);
if(s.length() == 1) sb.append('0');
sb.append(s);
}
return sb.toString();} catch (Exception e) { android.util.Log.v("TAG","Exception ["+e.getMessage()+"]", e); } return ""; }
```

Please help!